# Jersey 1.19 validate path and request parameters before they are injected into request handler method

Tags: java, jersey

I have the following request handler

```
@GET
ResponseEntity getEntity(@PathParam("pathParam") String pathParam,
                         @QueryParam("locale") String locale) {
    validate(pathParam);
    validate(locale);
    ...
}
```

I have a few handlers like above and they all validate request params and path params. I want to get rid of validation logic inside request handlers and do it at one place before they are injected.

Comment: If you can upgrade to jersey 2, you might use bean validation for it (JSR 303)

Answer (score 0):

Have filter class, which overrides the `ContainerRequestFilter`, so that all the request will pass through that filter. And write your validation logic inside filter class.

For Example

```
  public class MyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
      public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) throws WebApplicationException {

            //DO all your validations here
            //throw exception if validation fails
              if(!isValidInputs())
                throw new WebApplicationException("Invalid Inputs");

            //Else the flow is continued and the request will reach its handler method.

        return containerRequest;
      }
  }
```

And in `web.xml` mention this class as one the request filters.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>MyRequestFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern> /myapplication </url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

As jan.suppol alluded to. You will probably want to use the jsr303 implementation that jersey supports. You have to include the [jersey bean validation framework.](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)

I have found this to be the best way to handle validation of values.

```
@GET
@Path("{entityId}/ts")
public TimeSeries<Map<Metric, Number>> getTimeSeriesMap(@PathParam("entityId") final Long entityId,
        @QueryParam("c") @NotNull(message = "chronoUnit param 'c' is ia required") final String chronoUnitParam,
        @QueryParam("s") @NotNull(message = "start date 's' is required") final String startDateParam,
        @QueryParam("e") @NotNull(message = "endDate param 'e' is i required") final String endDateParam,
        @QueryParam("tsf") final String timestampFormat) throws StatsException {
```

This will collect the violations and send them all together back to the client. You will probably want to write your own [ExceptionMapper](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to format the exeptions in a usable manner.

Here is a quick example of mine. You would need to format the response for the requested media type.

```
@Provider
static class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    public ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        ConstraintViolationErrorResponse entity = ConstraintViolationErrorResponse.from(exception);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> v : exception.getConstraintViolations()) {
                // Handle your response as needed.
                logger.debug("Validation constraint occurred {} ", v.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(entity).build();
    }
}
```

Note that you can also use the @Valid annotation on an entity that is being posted and this will delegate the validation to the entities validation constraints.

So if you had an entity that looked like this.

public class Person extends AbstractDomainEntity {

```
@NotNull(message = "first name is required")
@Field
private String firstname;
...
}
```

You could write a post method like so.

```
@POST
public void save(@Valid Person person) {
...
}
```

If the firstname is null in this case then it will throw a constraintviolation exception. Check out the [ConstraintViolation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) to see what information it contains about the issue. The path may be especially useful if you are trying to propagate messages back to your user using a form.